# Was Jesus two separate individuals in one body?

Tags: nature-of-god, soteriology, christology, hypostatic-union

I have always been told, and I thoroughly believe that Jesus was wholly God and wholly man.

Since there are multiple occasions in the Bible where pre-incarnate Jesus apparently appeared to people, and yet we know that Jesus was  also born in human form to Mary, I feel that there had to be both a man Jesus and a deity Jesus occupying that same human body.

I hope that no-one will think that that is in any way Heretical and I certainly am not questioning the Deity of any part of the Trinity.

I have pondered that for quite some time and included the following in trying to come up with an answer.

1. When God created man he breathed the breath of life into only the man he created from dust. He has not breathed the breath of life into any others including Eve, and yet man continues to have the breath of life in posterity even to today.

   Does this indicate that we are still sharing the same breath of life that God breathed into the first man?
2. God told man that when he partook of the knowledge of good and evil that that life would be demanded back for hs disobedience.
3. Since God is eternal is not the breath of life also eternal?
4. When Jesus died on the cross was it that same life given to original man that he sacrificed?
5. If that were so then it would fulfill the demand of God that man must surely die.
6. When we surrender to Christ are we too sacrificing that same breath of life given to original man.
7. That would tend to further explain why Jesus death on the cross gives us forgiveness for our sins.
8. That also helps me to understand the following scriptures:

   Matt 10:39:  He that findeth his life shall lose it: and he that loseth his life for my     sake shall find it.

   Matt 16:25:  For whosoever will save his life shall lose it: and whosoever will lose    his life for my sake shall find it.

   Matt 19:17:  And he said unto him, Why callest thou me good? there is none good     but one, that is, God: but if thou wilt enter into life, keep the commandments.

   Luke 14:26:  If any man come to me, and hate not his father, and mother, and    wife, and children, and brethren, and sisters, yea, and his own life also, he cannot    be my disciple.

   John 5:24:  Verily, verily, I say unto you, He that heareth my word, and believeth  on him that sent me, hath everlasting life, and shall not come into condemnation;   but is passed from death unto life.

   John 17:3:  And this is life eternal, that they might know thee the only true God,  and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent.

And it causes me to believe that not only do we become a new creature when we accept Christ, but that he gives us a new eternal life.

> **[John 10:28](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2010:22-42&version=KJV)** (KJV)
>   And I give unto them eternal life; and they shall never perish, neither
>   shall any man pluck them out of my hand.
>
> **[John 17:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2017:1-5&version=KJV)** (KJV)
>   As thou hast given him power over all flesh, that he should give eternal
>   life to as many as thou hast given him.

Do any Theologians or denominations share those beliefs or am I just off my rocker?

Comment: Ceci., I think the mystery of the Cross is a mystery of love and can only be understood in prayer. So there is no answer to this question.

Comment: I feel like there's a lot here that doesn't really have anything to do with the actual question.

Comment: Possible duplicate (?): [Has the distinction of the human and divine natures in Jesus Christ been established?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6311/4188)

Comment: Ask a summa question, [get a summa answer](http://newadvent.org/summa/4.htm) maybe some day some one can write a _summa_ry

Comment: Regarding the final line - of course it could be both ;-). The title question sounds very Nestorian, though I don't know Nestor's theology of the "breath of life".

Comment: @Peter, yes, the question summarizes a number of questions about the Creation, a mystery of love.

Comment: It's not that mysterious.  Jesus is a 3 part being with a spirit that was alive and connected with God at birth.  We were born with disconnected (dead) spirits.  That's why we had to be born again... a new spirit was birthed in us and now we can relate to God spirit to Spirit.  - 1 thes 5:23, John 3:1-5, 2 Cor 5:23.

Comment: Hello Cecil, I have formatted you bible verses and provided links. Click edit to see how to properly do that.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Westminster Confession of Faith:

> The Son of God, the second person in the Trinity, being very and eternal God, of one substance and equal with the Father, did, when the fulness of time was come, take upon Him man's nature,(1) with all the essential properties and common infirmities thereof, yet without sin;(2) being conceived by the power of the Holy Ghost, in the womb of the Virgin Mary, of her substance.(3) So that **two whole, perfect, and distinct natures, the Godhead and the manhood, were inseparably joined together in one person**, without conversion, composition, or confusion.(4) Which person is very God...

This appears to suggest that your "two persons" theory is mistaken, because Christ is *one* person with two natures. Whether or not this answers your question rather depends on your view of WCF, and assumes that your definition of person is the same as that used by WCF.

Comment: How do you couple that with; Joh_10:30  I and my Father are one. Which would indicate that God was one with a human being?

Comment: @CecilBeckum One, as in when two people are married and become one. They aren't one person, but one in purpose, goals, and mindset. Two different people and personalities.

Comment: @ jLaverde from your comment I'm unable to discern whether you are agreeing or disagreeing with the precept of whether or not Jesus was two separate individuals in one body.

Answer (score 0):

Jesus is the Son of Man and the Son of God the Father.

Jesus is the Creator:

> Ephesians 3:9 And to make all men see what is the fellowship of the mystery, which from the beginning of the world hath been hid in God, who created all things by Jesus Christ

Jesus Creates from the “will” of God the Father:

> John 5:19 Then answered Jesus and said unto them, Verily, verily, I say unto you, The Son can do nothing of himself, but what he seeth the Father do: for what things soever he doeth, these also doeth the Son likewise.

Only those that do the will of God the Father are related to Jesus:

> Matthew 12:48-50 But he answered and said unto him that told him, Who is my mother? and who are my brethren… for whosoever shall do the will of my Father which is in heaven, the same is my brother, and sister, and mother.

Jesus Christ is the eternal manifest-will of God the Father, eternally born of the Holy Spirit. When the “Word became flesh”, it was not so we could ponder what divine flesh might be, but that the imagination of the heart of man might be fully enabled to it’s divine calling.

> John 4:23,24 But the hour cometh, and now is, when the true worshippers shall worship the Father in spirit and in truth: for the Father seeketh such to worship him.God is a Spirit: and they that worship him must worship him in spirit and in truth.

The incarnation was not to hold God captive within human form, but rather that mankind through a relationship with Jesus Christ might be made spiritually alive.

> 1 Corinthians 15:45 And so it is written, The first man Adam was made a living soul; the last Adam was made a quickening spirit

Comment: I agree with everything you have said, but cannot discern how it answers my question. since man was created in the image of God (that is to say with three parts body, soul and Spirit). After physical death man will be reduced to Spirit and Soul, and of the two only the Spirit will be able to worship.

Comment: @CecilBeckum, What I am attempting to say is that our view of Jesus must be an eternal perspective that is not bound by physical form.  While Jesus became flesh, His flesh does not encapsulate Him.  We must allow the imagination of our hearts to incorporate His role as Creator in addition to His role as Savior.  Physical constraints as extensions of a fallen world can fall well short of eternal realities.